# OpenGL lighting changing based on look direction

Tags: c++, c++11, opengl, sfml

AKA What am I doing wrong?

I've been messing around with OpenGL and I'm just trying to work on lighting a cube right now. I'm not sure if I'm understanding what I'm supposed to do correctly because when I move the camera around, the lighting on the cube changes.

For example:

Looking at the cube from the top down:

[image: top down]

Looking at the cube from the side:

[image]

From searching around all of the answers that I've seen say that this happens when the normal isn't set correctly, but I think they are being set correctly, because when I print out all of the vertices along with their normals, this is the result (grouped by face, in the order they're drawn):

```
Position:  0  0  0       Normal:   -1  0  0
Position:  0 30  0       Normal:   -1  0  0
Position:  0 30 30       Normal:   -1  0  0
Position:  0  0 30       Normal:   -1  0  0

Position:  0  0  0       Normal:    0  1  0
Position:  0  0 30       Normal:    0  1  0
Position: 30  0 30       Normal:    0  1  0
Position: 30  0  0       Normal:    0  1  0

Position:  0  0  0       Normal:    0  0 -1
Position: 30  0  0       Normal:    0  0 -1
Position: 30 30  0       Normal:    0  0 -1
Position:  0 30  0       Normal:    0  0 -1

Position:  0  0 30       Normal:    0  0  1
Position:  0 30 30       Normal:    0  0  1
Position: 30 30 30       Normal:    0  0  1
Position: 30  0 30       Normal:    0  0  1

Position:  0 30  0       Normal:    0 -1  0
Position: 30 30  0       Normal:    0 -1  0
Position: 30 30 30       Normal:    0 -1  0
Position:  0 30 30       Normal:    0 -1  0

Position: 30  0  0       Normal:    1  0  0
Position: 30  0 30       Normal:    1  0  0
Position: 30 30 30       Normal:    1  0  0
Position: 30 30  0       Normal:    1  0  0
```

Here's also some of the code used for rendering in case the mistake is in there:

```
RenderEngine::RenderEngine(int width, int height) {
    //initializing the window...

    glClearDepth(1.f);
    glClearColor(217.f / 256.f, 233.f / 256.f, 255.f / 256.f, 1.f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDepthMask(GL_TRUE);

    glFrontFace(GL_CW);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);

    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);

    //glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

    GLfloat lightPos[] = { 0.f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.f  };
    GLfloat ambient[] = {0.3f,0.3f,0.3f,1.0f};
    GLfloat diffuse[] = {0.7f,0.7f,0.7f,1.0f};
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, ambient);
    glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, diffuse);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

    //more window related things
}

void RenderEngine::beginRender() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}

void RenderEngine::endRender() {
    //window stuff
}

void RenderEngine::translatePlayer(const sf::Vector3f& position) {
    glTranslatef(-(position.x + 0.5) * 30, -(position.y + 1.75)  * 30, -(position.z + 0.5) * 30);
}

void RenderEngine::rotatePlayer(const sf::Vector3f& rotation) {
    glRotatef(rotation.x, 1.f, 0.f, 0.f);
    glRotatef(rotation.y, 0.f, 1.f, 0.f);
    glRotatef(rotation.z, 0.f, 0.f, 1.f);
}

void RenderEngine::renderVertexArray(const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices) {
    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

    glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].pos[0]);
    glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].color[0]);
    glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, sizeof(Vertex), &vertices[0].normal[0]);

    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, vertices.size());

    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
    glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);
}
```

And the vertex object:

```
struct Vertex {
    float pos[3];
    float color[3];
    float normal[3];

    Vertex(float _pos[3], float _color[3], float _normal[3]) :
        pos   {_pos[0],    _pos[1],    _pos[2]},
        color {_color[0],  _color[1],  _color[2]},
        normal{_normal[0], _normal[1], _normal[2]} {}

    Vertex() : pos{0,0,0}, color{0,0,0}, normal{0,0,0} {}
};
```

Please ignore all the random 30's. I'm aware that those are out of place and should not be done that way, but that's not the issue here.

Comment: I understand that you are only working or messing around with OpenGL but this is some advice; I wouldn't try to learn the Legacy versions of OpenGL in which by the looks of it you are using OpenGL 1.0. And I would look into learning modern OpenGL anything from version 3.3 to current 4.5. Here are a couple of excellent websites to learn OpenGL http://learnopengl.com/  and http://www.MarekKnows.com The first is 100% modern and is text based, the 2nd site has both Legacy and Modern but is downloadable video tutorial with low priced affordable membership.

Comment: What's the advantage / is it worth upgrading the whole project?

Comment: Sorry for not responding sooner. The advantages lies in the fact that with modern OpenGL shaders are used to do all the processing of vertices on the GPU side as opposed to the CPU. The GPUs are much more efficient at handling the calculations. Also, by using modern OpenGL over the Legacy API it is veering away from the "fixed function" pipeline, another words with using GLSL shaders  the Vertex, Geometry, Fragment (pixel) shaders, and others allows you the programmer to modify that function pipeline making modern OpenGL a programmable pipeline.

Comment: Well you have two choices, you could either try to upgrade the existing project, or just create a new project and start from the beginning. This would depend on how far along your current project is and how large it is. If your current project is extremely large, then there are downsides to both approaches: the downside to upgrading is the restructuring process and making sure you don't break anything with many hours of debugging, the downside of starting over is the time and work involved with getting caught up. If your project is small then it isn't too much of a hassle.

Comment: If the project is large, I would start a new project and copy over libraries and objects that work without the need to be updated and structure the application to work with modern OpenGL. For example; you may have a few utility classes that are independent of OpenGL itself where you just happen to load in image files for the use of textures, you can import them into the new engine and modify slightly to work with the new code base. The main difference is when creating your window and setting up the OpenGL context to begin rendering, as well as setting up the ability to use shaders.

Comment: Hmm okay well seems like I definitely should upgrade. Gonna take some learning but luckily I constrained all of my OpenGL calls to one class that all of the other classes interface with so hopefully I won't have to change much other than that one class. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the following:

```
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, lightPos);
```

... then the passed `lightPos` is transformed with the current model-view matrix and then stored in camera coordinates. Thus, your light will move together with the camera. If you want it to be static, you have to execute the above line again after setting the model-view matrix.

Comment: Ohh I see. I wasn't aware that it transformed it like that. Looks like now the lighting is static, but the brightness is a little wonky. But I'll just have to play with the parameters to get that tuned in. Thanks!