# openGL Rotate Sphere with fix light

Tags: opengl

i want to rotate a Sphere. And the light should be on a fix position in the room.
But it seems that the light is not on a fix position but rotate with the sphere. 
I tried to put everything in push/popmatrix. Doesn't help.
I read about normal but I also read that glut does it automaticlly with spheres.

How can I fix the light position?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl\gl.h>
#include <gl\glu.h>
#include <gl\glut.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>

float angletest = 1;
float winwidth, winheight;

void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{

switch (key)
{
case'\033':
    exit(0);
    break;
}
}

void reshape(w, h)
GLsizei w;
GLsizei h;
{
int size;

winwidth = w;
winheight = h;
size = w>h ? h : w;
glViewport(0, 0, size, size);       
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);    
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(40, 1.0, 1.0f, 20.0f);
glutPostRedisplay();
}

void display(void)
{
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();

GLUquadricObj *quadric;
quadric = gluNewQuadric();

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0);
glRotatef(angletest, 0, 0, 1);
gluSphere(quadric, 0.2, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
glRotatef(angletest, 0, 0, 1);
glTranslatef(0, 0.5, 0);
glutSolidSphere(0.2, 50, 50);
glPopMatrix();

glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();

}

void init()
{
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL);

glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

GLfloat mat_specular[] = { 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 };
GLfloat mat_shininess[] = { 50.0 };
GLfloat light_position[] = { 0, 0.5, 0, 1.0f };

glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SPECULAR, mat_specular);
glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_SHININESS, mat_shininess);
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);

glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);

}

void idle(void)
{
angletest = angletest + 0.05;

glutPostRedisplay();
}

void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
glutInitWindowSize(400, 400);
glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
glutInit(&argc, argv);
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

glutCreateWindow("test");

glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
glutDisplayFunc(display);
glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
glutIdleFunc(idle);
init(); 
glutMainLoop();

}
```

Tried to do it like mentioned below and put the

```
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
```

between glRotatef(angletest, 0, 0, 1); and gluSphere(quadric, 0.2, 50, 50);
But that didn't do it as well.

```
glPushMatrix(); 
glColor3f(0, 0, 1); 
glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0); 
glRotatef(angletest, 0, 0, 1); 
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position); 
gluSphere(quadric, 0.2, 50, 50); 
glPopMatrix();
```

Actually, i wanted the lightsource to be in the middle. But if i put it in the position 0,0,0 there is no light at all.
To make clear what I mean by moving light, I have three pictures here.

[light is in the right corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJMWy.png)

[light is in the left down corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIHAz.png)

So you can see it seems like the light is moving with the objects.
But what I want is the light to stay in the middle and give lights to the object like if it was a sun.

Comment: You are using legacy fixed-function OpenGL pipeline that had been deprecated for more than eight years. You should switch to the programmable pipeline of modern OpenGL instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenGL lighting changing based on look direction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39175271/opengl-lighting-changing-based-on-look-direction)

Comment: @NicoSchertler I read this thread before. But I'm not quite sure where I set the model-view matrix and have to write glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position); again. Out of frustation I tried to put it everywhere possible. But with no changes.

Comment: Between `glRotatef()` and `gluSphere()`.

Comment: glPushMatrix();
 glColor3f(0, 0, 1);
 glTranslatef(0.5, 0, 0);
 glRotatef(angletest, 0, 0, 1);
 glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position);
 gluSphere(quadric, 0.2, 50, 50);
 glPopMatrix();               But that ddidnt do it

Comment: I don't see why you would get the impression of a moving light source with this code, no matter if you put the `glLightfv` into init or between the rotation and translate. In both cases, the light will be stationary with respect to your view point, it will just be on slightly different positions. (And it is kind of weird to use `w=0.5`  for the light position, you probably don't want that.). Are you sure that the light actually is _wrong_? You should see the moving highlight in that scenario. Also, you are leaking the quadric object in your render loop.

Comment: @derhass I edited the question. Maybe the pictures make it more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my comment was wrong. I just realized that you don't use the matrix stack to transform the camera (the view part in model-view) but the object space (the model part). `glLightfv()` should be called after you change the view part and before you change the model part. But you never change the view part in your code, so setting up the light once is sufficient.

There is another subtle problem in your code, which causes this behavior. Take a look at your `reshape()` function. You change the matrix mode to projection and never change it back to model-view. Hence, all matrix transformations that you apply are applied to the projection matrix. Lighting is calculated in view space. And since you do not change the model-view matrix, all lighting is done in the object's coordinate system (assuming the light position in this system). The projection matrix then rotates the already illuminated object, possibly away from the light.

So the solution is simple: Switch the matrix mode back to model-view in your `reshape()` function.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Unfortunately when I write it like this: glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluPerspective(40, 1.0, 1.0f, 20.0f);
 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 glutPostRedisplay();       i cannot see anything anymore

Comment: Because you now have a perspective matrix that you didn't have before (you removed it by the subsequent call to `glLoadIdentity()` in `display()`. Remove the perspective transform and you should see something again.

Comment: thanks. this was it. I additionally needed to delete the glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position); two times. But now it workes. Thank